How can I adjust the sensitivity of my Xbox controllers' analog sticks in Windows 11?
One of my Xbox controllers has super-sensitive analog sticks where just moving them out to the halfway point spikes them to max sensitivity, making it very difficult to aim or move around.
My other controller, which is awaiting repair, has "normal" sensitivity proportionate to its position from neutral to outer ring. How can I adjust these individually?
I envision a sort of graph where I can plot a line from the lower-left corner straight up to the upper-right corner, indicating a proportionate increase in sensitivity. As it is now, such a graph would spike to the top at the midway point. I am on Windows 11 and have tried the calibration tool, but it doesn't offer the robust configuration options I need.
Something else is that the longer I hold the stick to the outer edge, the faster it goes until it reaches a cap after about a second. It's like there's some kind of progressive sensitivity. It doesn't do this with my other Xbox controller.

This "progressive sensitivity" you mention is most likely a symptom of stick drift. The reason your controller maxes out at the midpoint is possibly because the drift interfered with calibration, making your PC think that the midpoint is actually the outer edge.
